# Как удалить лэйбл в ткинтере при вызове функции?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Я изучаю питон 3, и решил сделать небольшую программу которая решала бы квадратные уравнения с дискриминантом. Все работает и она решает, но лейблы накидываются друг на друга когда нажимаю на кнопку несколько раз, я пытался удалять лейблы, но не сработало, всегда что-то мешает. Я прикрепил код, простите что он не очень организован, но это не главная проблема, пожалуйста подскажите как мне надо удалять лейблы чтобы не было ошибки типа *name x_label is not defined*, я много всего пытался сделать и ничего не получается. Задавайте вопросы если надо что-то уточнить.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()

a_label = Label(root, text="Enter the value of a: ")
a_entry = Entry(root, borderwidth=4)

b_label = Label(root, text="Enter the value of b: ")
b_entry = Entry(root, borderwidth=4)

c_label = Label(root, text="Enter the value of c: ")
c_entry = Entry(root, borderwidth=4)

a_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
a_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

b_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
b_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

c_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
c_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)


def start():
    global a, b, c, D, x_label, x12_label
    a = a_entry.get()
    b = b_entry.get()
    c = c_entry.get()
    D = float(b) * float(b) - 4 * float(a) * float(c)
    if D < 0:
        d_less0()
    elif D == 0:
        d_0()
    else:
        d_more0()


def d_less0():
    error_msg = messagebox.showerror("Error", "No roots, because D is less than 0")


def d_0():
    x = float(b) / -1 / (2 * float(a))
    x_label = Label(text="D is equal to 0, therefore only one root, which is equal to " + str(x))
    x_label.grid(row=6, column=2)


def d_more0():
    x1 = (float(b) / -1 + sqrt(D)) / (2 * float(a))
    x2 = (float(b) / -1 - sqrt(D)) / (2 * float(a))
    x12_label = Label(root, text="Found two roots, x1 = " + str(x1) + " x2 = " + str(x2))
    x12_label.grid(row=6, column=2)


check_btn = Button(root, text="Solve", command=start)
check_btn.grid(row=3, column=1)




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059974/how-to-delete-or-destroy-label-in-tkinter

Comment: Когда я ввожу x_label.destroy() где угодно мне говорит name x_label is not defined, какие возможные причины?

Comment: Причина в том, что `x_label` у вас локальная переменная, в других функциях она не видна.

Comment: Что я должен с этим сделать? Проблема в том что x_label или x12_label должны появляться только после нажатия на кнопку, должен ли я использовать global? И как конкретнее? Спасибо

Comment: Да, global, причем в тех функциях, где происходит создание самих Label.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте переменные

```
x_label=0
x12_label=0
```

а далее в функциях

```
global x_label
```

---

`global x12_label`

Comment: Не нужно таким образом "создавать" переменные, достаточно только пометить что они глобальные внутри функций.